# Array slicing / group_concat limiting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a table:

```
i j
---
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
b 5
b 6
b 7
b 8
b 9
```

Obvoiusly `SELECT a, GROUP_CONCAT(b SEPARATOR ',') GROUP BY a` would give me

```
a  1,2,3,4
b  5,6,7,8,9
```

But what if I want to get only a LIMITED number of results, like 2, for example:

```
a  1,2
b  5,6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to get a limited *number* of results, or a specific subset?  I.e. do you want only two results, or do you want 1,2 from a, and 4,5 from b?

Comment: Agree, question needs clarification.

Comment: limited number of results (2 results), "4,5"  should be "5,6" of course - a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT i, SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(j), ',', 2)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY i;
```

You don't have to know the length of `j` field here.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to limit the rows in the group to the top two, before computing the aggregate.

```
SELECT t.i, GROUP_CONCAT(t.j)
FROM
  (SELECT t1.i, t1.j
   FROM mytable AS t1
     LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2
       ON (t1.i = t2.i AND t1.j >= t2.j) 
   GROUP BY t1.i, t1.j
   HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2) AS t
GROUP BY t.i;
```

Another solution, if you know the values in `j` are of a fixed length, is to simply use `SUBSTRING()` on the result:

```
SELECT i, SUBSTRING( GROUP_CONCAT(j), 1, 3 )
FROM mytable
GROUP BY i;
```